# How to create auto connection to language table [Article to Article_lang]

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

I have an idea.

We should create a function to auto connect from a class to its language class.
Ex: Articles connect to Articles_lang.

Default, we have:

```
belongsTo()
hasOne()
hasMany()
belongsToMany()
```

Maybe, we need add one more:

```
hasMultiLangFields()
```

Ex:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMultiLangFields(['title', 'body']);
    }
}
```

I want when i using query in Controller, it will auto find values from Articles_lang

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function view($id)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('article'));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$article->id = 12
$article->created = 2015-05-29T05:09:36+0000
$article->title = title 12
$article->body = body 12
```

---

Database:

```
= articles =
id           |  int(10) Primary
created      |  datetime
modified     |  datetime

= articles_lang =
id_articles  |  int(11)
id_lang      |  int(11)
title        |  varchar(150)
body         |  text
```

How can i get this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] Maybe, we need add one more

Or maybe we don't. Not only does the core supply translation functionality, there are also plugins out there handling this.

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html**
- **https://github.com/AD7six/cakephp-shadow-translate**